# Validate each dropdown (select list) related to a product

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-selectors

We have a table that has a product record on each row. Each product may have from zero to 6 dropdowns (we call them option groups) associated with it. If a customer enters a quantity greater than zero I need to make sure they have made a selection from each dropdown (if there is a dropdown for that product). Any ideas? Here's a sample table and then my jquery code.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="GroupRow">
  <td valign="top"><strong>
    <input name="ItemQty1" type="text" id="ItemQty1" class="ItemQuantity" value="1" size="4" maxlength="3" style="width:20px;" />
    </strong></td>
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td valign="top"><strong>Arctic Armor Suit Black Suit </strong>
    <div id="pd-optionsContainer_1" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Jacket Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_1" id="ParentID_1" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11053">Medium</option>
        <option value="10543">Large</option>
        <option value="13751">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7300">2X-Large</option>
        <option value="7696">3X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      Bib Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_2" id="ParentID_2" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11052">Medium</option>
        <option value="10542">Large</option>
        <option value="13750">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7310">2X-Large</option>
        <option value="7703">3X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      Glove Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_3" id="ParentID_3" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11054">Medium</option>
        <option value="10517">Large</option>
        <option value="13737">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7295">2X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; </div></td>
  <td valign="top"><strong>$329.99</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr class="GroupRow">
  <td valign="top"><input name="ItemQty2" type="text" id="ItemQty2" class="ItemQuantity" value="0" size="4" maxlength="3" style="width:20px;" /></td>
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td valign="top">Arctic Armor Gloves
    <div id="pd-optionsContainer_2" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_4" id="ParentID_4" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11056">Medium</option>
        <option value="10519">Large</option>
        <option value="13739">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7297">2X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; </div></td>
  <td valign="top">$29.99 </td>
</tr>
</table>



    $('tr.GroupRow input.ItemQuantity').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).val() > 0){
            alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
            $('tr.GroupRow').find('select.OptionsSelected').each(function(index) {
                //if ($(this).val() > 0){
                    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
                //}
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working [jsFiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/jFXZ4/).  Fun problem to solve.  Thanks. :)

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="GroupRow">
  <td valign="top"><strong>
    <input name="ItemQty1" type="text" id="ItemQty1" class="ItemQuantity" value="1" size="4" maxlength="3" style="width:20px;" />
    </strong></td>
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td valign="top"><strong>Arctic Armor Suit Black Suit </strong>
    <div id="pd-optionsContainer_1" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Jacket Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_1" id="ParentID_1" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11053">Medium</option>
        <option value="10543" selected>Large</option>
        <option value="13751">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7300">2X-Large</option>
        <option value="7696">3X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      Bib Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_2" id="ParentID_2" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11052">Medium</option>
        <option value="10542">Large</option>
        <option value="13750">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7310">2X-Large</option>
        <option value="7703">3X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;

  Glove Size:&nbsp;
  <select name="OptionID_3" id="ParentID_3" class="OptionsSelected">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="11054">Medium</option>
    <option value="10517">Large</option>
    <option value="13737">X-Large</option>
    <option value="7295">2X-Large</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp; </div></td>
  <td valign="top"><strong>$329.99</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr class="GroupRow">
  <td valign="top"><input name="ItemQty2" type="text" id="ItemQty2" class="ItemQuantity" value="0" size="4" maxlength="3" style="width:20px;" /></td>
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td valign="top">Arctic Armor Gloves
    <div id="pd-optionsContainer_2" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Size:&nbsp;
      <select name="OptionID_4" id="ParentID_4" class="OptionsSelected">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="11056">Medium</option>
        <option value="10519">Large</option>
        <option value="13739">X-Large</option>
        <option value="7297">2X-Large</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; </div></td>
  <td valign="top">$29.99 </td>
</tr>
</table>

$('tr.GroupRow').each(function(index, element) {
    if($(element).find('input').val() > 0) {
        alert('row ' + index + ' has a quantity greater than zero');
        $('select', element).each(function(index, element) {
            if($('option:selected', element).val() === '') {
               alert('option ' + index + ' is not selected!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to both Jimmy and Nick. You guys make this stuff look easy.

Comment: consider putting your actual answer right in your StackOverflow answer in addition to linking to it on jsfiddle.  That way lazy people can check it out immediately (and if jsfiddle happens to be down, they can actually see the answer! :)

Comment: I thought I could turn this into a form validation function on my own, but I need help. I don't want the form to submit if an option is not selected. But using return false only stops the submission if an option isn't selected during the final loop through the final product row. Does that make sense? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Skyetech, you need to create a little object to collect the state of each row.  An array of true/false would work.  You can then use a library like underscore.js to determine if there are any 'false' values in the array to block the form submission.

Comment: Jimmy, you gave me a great idea. I'm using the following code to check my array and haven't found a problem yet:
`    if(errorArray.indexOf("false") > -1){
        alert('don\'t submit!');
    } else {
       alert('submit!');
    }
`

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy beat me to it - but I did my own version in jsBin. Perhaps not as clean but might help :)

http://jsbin.com/ororen